# ksh increment the while loop argument

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

In Ksh, I have a while loop that reads 2 files. If current line of file 1 is "Y" then echo the current line of file 2 into new file and if current line of file 1 is "N" echo "waste" in winscp.

```
    while IFS= read xxxx && IFS= read yyyy <&4; do
if [[ ${xxxx} = "N" ]];then
      echo waste
   else
      echo "$yyyy" .>> $newfile
   fi
done <"$file1" 4<"$file2"
```

But if the file 1 has first three lines as N and remaining seven as Y, instead on printing three times "waste" and the last seven lines of second file into new file, my Winscp is displaying 10 times "waste" while running the script.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I did not succeed in reproducing the problem. I do not know why. Do you have special input files, is ksh behaving different than my bash or did you made an over-simplification making this example. Giving the input files might help.

Comment: Please check my latest reply to your answer to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is the same number of lines in file1 and file2 AND that each line of file1 is either N or Y you could use something like that :

```
    #!/bin/ksh

    testArray=($(cat file1.txt))

    i=0

    while read line; do
        if [[ ${testArray[$i]} == "N" ]]; then
            print "waste"
        else
            print $line >> file3.txt
        fi
        ((i++))
    done < file2.txt
```

Or following comments

```
    #!/bin/ksh


    while read -r -u 3 line1 && read -r -u 4 line2; do
            if [[ $line1 == "N" ]]; then
                    print "waste"
            else
                    print $line2 >> file3.txt
            fi
    done 3<file1.txt 4<file2.txt
```

Works on my (very) small test files...

Comment: Hi Andre. Thank you for the response. I also thought of array methods. But actual file lines may go up to billion lines (equal on both files). Does array has capacity to store the much subscripts.

Comment: It depends, but 4194303 is the usual maximum index in ksh93. When you say, billion...you mean "a lot" or literally ? On the other hand, I don't think bash has an actual maximum save for the amount of memory ( but don't quote me on that ;) )

Comment: @GowthamSarathy I've added a new one that looks like working according to your comment.

Comment: Hi Andre. I have tried the second option. But still the outputs are same as what i have mentioned in the main question. I made a file1 having 10 lines (NYYNYYYYYN) so I should have got 7 records from the file2 into the file3 and 3 times "waste" but i got 10 times "waste" only.

Comment: As it working perfectly well on my side, maybe it's your file2 (my file2 contains only a number per line) ? Can you give us an example of the lines ? And just to be sure, you have tested with only this code nothing else ?

Comment: Hi Andre. It worked now. I found a line with blank space in file 1. After removal it works. Thank you.

Comment: Happy to hear this. Please consider choosing an answer so people will know you're not looking for one anymore. Nice Day !

Comment: I have marked your answer as correct as it worked fine. SECOND OPTION in your answer is viable way. Also using array as in FIRST OPTION as works fine but some systems has array size limits so i suggest second option in your answer codes.

Answer (score 0):

I can not see what is the problem. Perhaps `file1` has other characters after the 'N', like a space `N`, other characters `NO`, or a `\r` (Windows file).  Or lowercase `n`.

Another solution might be using `paste`. Look for a character that is not in file1 (for example a `#`), and use that character for pasting the two files together.
And test the solution with 10 lines, not a billion (comment to other answer).

```
paste -d'#' file1 file2
```

Perhaps you see something strange on the lines that should start with `N#`.
Now you can use `sed` for `p` printing lines or `w` write to a file.

```
paste -d'#' file1 file2 | sed -n 's/^N#.*/waste/p;s/^[^#]*#//w newfile'
```

Comment: Hai. I'm confused with the answer. Let me show you the example of files and what is expected output.

Comment: You can use `printf "%s\n" N Y Y > file1; printf "%s\n" 1Content 2Content 3Content > file2` for making the test files and run the `paste` commands. The new file `newfile` should have the 2 desired lines, one time "waste" on stdout.

Comment: Hi Walter. If you are confused with my scenario, let me once once explain you.

file 1 (It will be there, we don't need to create it) (Each char in new line)
Y
Y
N

File 2(Already available) (Each in each line)
1Content
2Content
3Content

Output Expected: (each in new line)
New file:
1Content
2Content

and third iteration prints "waste"

Comment: Can I explain me once again about two of your codes in answer. I am not getting it clearly.

Comment: First look at the result of `paste -d'#' file1 file2` (replace file1 and file2 with the actual filenames). The result will be lines starting with `N#` or `Y#`. With `sed` you can replace the lines starting with `N#` with `waste`. Perhaps first look at `paste -d'#' file1 file2 | sed -n 's/^[^#]*#//p` where the waste is ignored and the first part of the other lines (until first `#`) is removed.